# How does smarttab actually works?

Tags: vimrc, indentation

Yes, I'm aware of what `:h smarttab` says, but I still cannot figure it out.

```
" My vimrc
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set tabstop=8 " I always keep this 8
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=-1 " To use the width of `shiftwidth`
set expandtab
set smarttab
```

> When on, a `<Tab>` in front of a line inserts blanks according to
> `shiftwidth`.  `tabstop` or `softtabstop` is used in other places.  A
> `<BS>` will delete a `shiftwidth` worth of space at the start of the
> line.
>
> When off, a `<Tab>` always inserts blanks according to `tabstop` or
> `softtabstop`.  `shiftwidth` is only used for shifting text left or
> right `shift-left-right`.

But I observe the same behavior even if `smarttab` is off. Pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key inserts 4 spaces, and pressing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes 4 spaces. Why does it happen? What is the reason to use `smarttab` then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason to use smarttab then?

As it is written in help, when `smarttab` is off, `softtabstop` is used everywhere including line start. However, if `softtabstop` is equal to -1 then it is set to `shiftwidth` anyway. Hence there'll be no difference in setting `smarttab` on or off.

In other words, `smarttab` is only meaningful *if both* `set expandtab` and `softtabstop` differs from `shiftwidth`. But normally it's not the case and we don't need `smarttab`.

Comment: _... if both `set expandtab` and `softtabstop` differs from `shiftwidth`_ -- I'm not sure I understand the mention of `expandtab` in this context. Since `expandtab` is a Boolean option, its value is _always_ different from the value of `shiftwidth`.

Comment: @james if **set** expandtab.

Comment: Probably you mean "if `expandtab` is set and if, at the same time, `softtabstop` differs from `shiftwidth`"? I'm sorry, although my name here is "James" (which is an English name), I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @james Me neither. I simply hope that I put it in a way that makes sense. Yes, if et is set and sts is not equal to sw.